# error al ejecutar kubeadm init

Tags: kubernetes

Estoy haciendo una instalación de `kubernetes` sobre un servidor que no tiene salida a Internet.

Lo primero que hice fue instalar bajo la guía https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/
de modo que he ejecutado:

```
yum install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl --disableexcludes=kubernetes
```

En el momento que hago un `kubeadm init` obtengo el siguiente mensaje:

> error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
>           [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.13.4: output: Trying to pull repository k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver ...
>   Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v1/_ping: dial tcp: lookup k8s.gcr.io on 127.0.0.1:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:33262->127.0.0.1:53: read: connection refused
>   , error: exit status 1

¿Qué es lo que puedo hacer?

Comment: Para intentar paliar el problema, estoy intentado descargarme este https://k8s.gcr.io/v1/_ping a un repo local mío.

También aparecen otros ficheros como k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy:v1.13.4 del cual ni soy capaz de descargarlo manualmente desde mi navegador para así llevarlo a mi repositorio.

Realmente me pregunto si se puede utilizar Kubernetes sin necesidad de salir a Internet. Caso de que así sea ¿Que alternativa podría usar que fuera open?

un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Como estás?. Por lo que tengo entendido no podes instalar K8s con Kubeadm sin Internet. Te esta dando error al hacer el Pull de los contenedores de configuración. Si vas a probar, te recomiendo minikube y en todo caso si tenés internet kubeadm para instalar de manera manual. Si te interesa ya automatizar podes investigar sobre kubespray.
Saludos!